# How to removeClass / addClass on page reload

Tags: jquery

I want to removeClass / addClass on click but since clicking also refresh the page it resets the html.

Any hint about how to solve this is really appreciated thanks.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/">All
      <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/category/C">CPU</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/category/R">RAM</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/category/G">GPU</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/category/CS">Case</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/category/HD">HardDisk</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.nav-item').on('click', function() {
        $('.nav-item.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
});
```

Is there a way for the js function to fire after the page reload?
Or any pratical way to accomplish the same result?
thank's for everyone time and suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered or looked into `localStorage`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: thanks, I'm looking into the documentation

Comment: Take a look at client-side storage in general, here are the options you can consider: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var current_path = window.location.pathname;
  $("a.nav-link").each(function() {
    var href = jQuery(this).attr("href");

    if (current_path.includes(href) || if (href.includes(current_path) || href == current_path) {) {
       $(this).parents(".nav-item").addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice! A really minor nit-pick, but this answer could be improved further if you move the variable declaration for `current_path` outside of the `.each()` loop. The browser will reference the same variable in memory with every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Sadly it doens't work, there's a small syntax error I fixed but still doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, it should work if you fixed the syntax error at the bottom. I edited my answer a little, maybe now it will work. You can console.log(href+"=="+current_path); to see if they look the same and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this with Javascript, you have to use server side logic for this (php, java,...) Or you are using react/angular then you can use their built in logic for setting the active state of a link.

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about php, java, react and angular, the only backend language I know is python.. Can it be used?

Comment: You could if you leveraged the browser or the user's PC as a storage object.

Answer (score 0):

As i get from your question, you can prevent of default behavior of a tag by js as you want in first section of your question by `preventDefault()` function:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav-item').on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.nav-item.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
});
```

and for a function that fire after page reload you:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    dosomething();
 });
```

It will run the js after the whole page is loaded.

and finally i hope understand you question correctly.

Comment: If you disable the default behaviour of the link you will also be preventing end-users from navigating anywhere, which I believe is still the intention.

Comment: yes, you are right, but i answer what i get from "Skalfaro" question